# IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands ) and LNK1120/2001 unresolved

Tags: lnk2001

I am working on a assignment for school and I am having some issues i havnet been able to figure out
I got 2 files Stundet.cpp and Student.h
in my Student.h i am declaring a Student class

```
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class Student
{private:
string fname;
string lname;
int ID;


public:
    Student();
    Student(string first,string last, int ID_num);
    static int numberOfStudents;
    void getName();
    void getID();

};
```

in my Student.cpp i got

```
`#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

 Student::Student()
{numberOfStudents+=1;
}

Student::Student(string first, string last, int ID_num)
{fname=first;
lname=last;
ID=ID_num;
numberOfStudents+=1;}

int Student::numberOfStudents=0;

void Student::getName()
{cout<<fname<<lname;}

void Student::getID()
{cout<<ID;}

main() 
{ 
 Student st1("Hakan", "Haberdar", 1234), st2("Charu", "Hans", 2345), st3("Tarikul", "Islam", 5442), st4; 
 cout << "We created " << Student::numberOfStudents << " student objects." << endl; 
 cout << st1.getID() << " " << st1.getName() << endl; 
 cout << st2.getID() << " " << st2.getName() << endl; 
 cout << st3.getID() << " " << st3.getName() << endl; 
 cout << st4.getID() << " " << st4.getName() << endl; 
system("pause"); 
} `
```

my first issue is that i keep getting these external errors that i have no idea how to fix, ive looked around but i dont really understand how to apply what i find. My errors are

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup    C:\Users\Tato- laptop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Student Class\Student Class\LINK

and

> Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Tato- laptop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Student Class\Debug\Student Class.exe   1

My second issues is that the couts in the .cpp file stopped working, i understand im supposed to overload them or something but I dont really understand how
Any help would be appreciated.